# Can't add a UIImage? to an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

When selecting the photos to display in the user's profile, while doing a `.onTapGesture` to append a UIImage into an array of them, Xcode throws `No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'`

```
.onTapGesture {
    isShowingPhotoPickerForPersonImage.toggle()
    Person.personImages.append([UIImage?])
}
```

---

```
struct Person: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var personImages: [UIImage?]
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring your UIImage as optional? Btw you should initialize your collection `var personImages: [UIImage] = []`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an array of `UIImage?` to the array, not a `UIImage?`.

```
.onTapGesture {
               isShowingPhotoPickerForPersonImage.toggle()
               Person.personImages.append(UIImage?) // Remove the brackets
 }
```

As noted in the comments, this is pretty non-sensical. You need to actually have an image to append. Lastly, the nice thing about using an `Array` is that you do not need to use an optional value in its declaration. It can always be simply empty if you don't have a value to declare it with originally. Then, instead of testing for `nil`, your test is `.isEmpty`.

Comment: OP should add the `UIImage` instance `someImage` not `UIImage` itself. **Btw `personImage` is NOT a static property**

Comment: What's ``someImage`` ?  and why should I make ``personImages`` a static property?

Comment: @LeoDabus Agreed, but I have to work with what I was given. It is non-sensical to add an optional UIImage.

Comment: Again `Person.personImages` is not a valid syntax. `personImage` is an instance property.

Comment: The best think to do in this case is to vote to close the question. OP is not showing where person object is declared/instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Youre `personImages`  is an Optional UIImage Array, you so should add `some Image` or nil。`UIImage?` is a type

Comment: what should ``var personImages: [UIImage] =`` be equal to?

Comment: You need to add the actual image, not just an optional of the `Type`.